# How to put a line of text on a new line in an object array so that the question is more legible?

Tags: javascript, html

The question is pertaining to the question key - value pair. Currently I am attempting to just put commas, I tried br thought I was 100% sure that wouldn't work.

question.js

```
var questions = [{
"question": "What order will the logs get printed? - JS Runtime in browser setTimeout(()=> {console.log('a')}, 100)<br />setTimeout(()=> {console.log('b')}, 0)\nPromise.resolve('c').then(console.log)\nconsole.log('d')",
"option1": "d, c, b, a",
"option2": "d, b, c, a",
"option3": "a, b, c, d",
"option4": "d, a, b, c",
"answer": "option1"}];
```

index.html

```
<div id="quizContainer" class="container">
        <div class="title">Computer Quiz</div>
        <div id="question" class="question"></div>
        <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="1" /> <span id="opt1"></span></label>
        <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="2" /> <span id="opt2"></span></label>
        <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="3" /> <span id="opt3"></span></label>
        <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="4" /> <span id="opt4"></span></label>
        <button id="nextButton" class="next-btn" onclick="loadNextQuestion();">Next Question</button>
    </div>

    <div id="result" class="container result"></div>
    
    <script src="question.js"></script>
    <script src="quiz-script.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `\n` will work in the console... But if you use `.innerHTML` to display the string on the page, that would be `<br>`.

Comment: Yes, I am not trying to console this. This is linked to an index.html page so it displays on the browser. My goal is break the question operations on a new line so that the user can read them and decide how they will execute. @Spectric

Answer (score 1):

```js
var questions = [{
    "question": "1 - What order will the logs get printed? - JS Runtime in browser setTimeout(()=> {console.log('a')}, 100)\nsetTimeout(()=> {console.log('b')}, 0)\nPromise.resolve('c').then(console.log)\nconsole.log('d')",
    "option1": "Abacus",
    "option2": "Analytical Engine",
    "option3": "Calculator",
    "option4": "Processor",
    "answer": "2"
}]

console.log(questions[0].question)
```

The character for a new line is `\n`

This code work if you need to output to DOM instead of console:

```js
var questions = [{
    "question": "1 - What order will the logs get printed? - JS Runtime in browser setTimeout(()=> {console.log('a')}, 100)<br />setTimeout(()=> {console.log('b')}, 0)<br />Promise.resolve('c').then(console.log)<br />console.log('d')",
    "option1": "Abacus",
    "option2": "Analytical Engine",
    "option3": "Calculator",
    "option4": "Processor",
    "answer": "2"
}]

document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = questions[0].question
```

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the UI?  \n works on the console. In html, the OP might need to insert <br/>

Comment: @danh yes it does, but it wasn't specified so I just made a suggestion.

Comment: *Because document.write() writes to the document stream, calling document.write() on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open(), which will clear the document.* [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I left it there just for demonstration purposes, maybe OP doesn't understand what DOM means, but when he runs the two examples he will see the difference between DOM and console. I will edit it to output to an element's innerHTML instead.

Comment: @DaishoArch this is a file named question.js , linked to the index.html, I have tried break, but it doesn't work and \n , the goal is to have the question be legible once outputted on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

To print the string in the document, use `.innerHTML`. For new lines, add some `<br/>` in the string.

Also... To display some code, you can use `<pre>` wich will display the text with the `monospace` font-family by default.

```js
var questions = [{
  "question": "1 - What order will the logs get printed? - JS Runtime in browser<br/><br/><pre>setTimeout(()=> {console.log('a')}, 100)<br/>setTimeout(()=> {console.log('b')}, 0)<br/>Promise.resolve('c').then(console.log)<br/>console.log('d')</pre>",
  "option1": "Abacus",
  "option2": "Analytical Engine",
  "option3": "Calculator",
  "option4": "Processor",
  "answer": "2"
}];

document.querySelector("#question").innerHTML = questions[0].question
```

```css
#question {
  padding: 1em;
}

#question pre {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="quizContainer" class="container">
  <div class="title">Computer Quiz</div>
  <div id="question" class="question"></div>
  <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="1" /> <span id="opt1"></span></label>
  <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="2" /> <span id="opt2"></span></label>
  <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="3" /> <span id="opt3"></span></label>
  <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="4" /> <span id="opt4"></span></label>
  <button id="nextButton" class="next-btn" onclick="loadNextQuestion();">Next Question</button>
</div>
<div id="result" class="container result" style="display:none;">
</div>
<script src="question.js"></script>
<script src="quiz-script.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's interesting that it running for you, yet it is not for me. Perhaps there is a problem with my quiz-script.js file that allows for selecting options and going to the next question that is interfering with the innerHTML.

Comment: I pushed the repo to git, if you wanna take a look at what I've built so far. I want to add 19 more questions. https://github.com/apollo-scripts/script-quiz

Comment: Here it is on [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=0110)

Comment: I changed `textContent` for `innerHTML` on line #29 of the codepen... So that is on line #16 of your quiz-script.js  - And added a bit of CSS.

Comment: Ho, I also used "my" version of the question... (Question.js line #2)

Comment: lol... I just noticed I did not save my CodePen yet!! :x lolll So the link is [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/OJmabyv?editors=0110)